# Full redirect using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do `window.location.replace = window.location.hostname + '/something'` in myexample.com/page, it will become `myexample.com/page/myexample.com/page/something`

How to do a full redirect?

Comment: `window.location.hostname` will give you `myexample.com` not `http://myexample.com`

Comment: @Apb so what should it be?

Comment: You can use `window.location.origin`.

Comment: window.location.replace is a function you call with a new url, relative or full. so, `location.replace("/something")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href`, which is the current location of the window.

To be sure, check if the last character is a `/`.

```
var current = window.location.href;
var append = current.slice(-1) === '/' ? 'something' : '/something';

window.location = current + append;
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: expando string access doesn't work in IE, so `.slice(-1)` would be more robust